# How an Android background service in a Huawei mobile phone can know if the user has changed into the "private space"?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am running a background service app in a Huawei mobile phone, and I would like to detect when the user changes into the private space that some Huawei mobile phones have (see https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us15834600/).

I have tried asking the OS for the number of installed applications since in the private space the installed apps are different, but that call returns the same number of applications as in the “ordinary space” (an app running from the beginning in the private space gets the right list of installed applications in the private space but my background service, since it “belongs” to the “ordinary space” gets the list of installed apps of the “ordinary space”).

I have also checked https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development but I am not capable of finding a solution. Does anyone know how to do it?

Many thanks in advance